# snprintf: Same code - different errors/warnings on different g++ compilers

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, printf

I know this question may have been asked before but hasn't answered the query I am posting below. I am trying to figure out why exactly the code below gives the error (and in other version of GCC, a warning) and esp. how to resolve this? I am an experienced C++ programmer, but sometimes you do need to seek for help. Any help is appreciated.

[ERROR]: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type ‘class std::basic_string’ through

```
/// USE THE MACRO BELOW TO LOG A FORMATTED STRING (usage is exactly like printf(...) [ SEE HEADER FILE - TEMPLATE FUNCTION user_log_fmt(...) ]
#define LOG_TRACE_FMT(...)  Logger::getInstance()->user_log_fmt(LOG_LEVEL_TRACE,   __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__)

void main()
{   
    std::string linkName = getLinkName();

    // THIS IS THE CALL THAT LEADS TO THE ERROR AT COMPILE-TIME
    LOG_TRACE_FMT("\nLink-name: %s, Sent packet: SYS: %d, COMP: %d, LEN: %d, MSG ID: %d\n", linkName, msg->sysid, msg->compid, msg->len, msg->msgid);
}
///
/// Part of logger class (combines strings with argument for formatting) 
///
template <typename ... Args>
void user_log_fmt(LOG_LEVEL level,  std::string pretty_func, std::string func_name, std::string str_format, Args ... args)
{
    if (m_LogLevel < level)
        return;

    std::string formatted_data = utils::Utils::string_format(str_format, args...);
    // Do something with the formatted string.. 
}

///
/// Part of Utils library. This method does a printf type formatting.
///
template<typename ... Args>
static std::string string_format( const std::string& format, Args ... args )
{
    size_t size = snprintf( nullptr, 0, format.c_str(), args ... ) + 1; // Extra space for '\0'
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf( new char[ size ] );
    snprintf( buf.get(), size, format.c_str(), args ... );
    return std::string( buf.get(), buf.get() + size - 1 ); // We don't want the '\0' inside
}
```

The error is with snprintf statement above.

> WARNING on g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609:

warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
size_t size = snprintf( nullptr, 0, format.c_str(), args ... ) + 1;'
                                   ^

> ERROR on g++ (Raspbian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2

error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type ‘class std::basic_string’ through ‘...’
size_t size = snprintf( nullptr, 0, format.c_str(), args ... ) + 1;

> Note: I wish to understand and resolve this but without providing a compiler flag setting. I understand this may have something to do with C
>   compatibility with C++.

Thanks!

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thanks for pointing out. But snprintf does relate to C, the reason I tagged it as C. The content is stored as c-string.

Comment: It seems to work with a C++14 online compiler: http://ideone.com/HfuHIx . How do you call the function?

Comment: @Sammy That's fine, but IMHO this question seeks answers based on C++ language and, C and C++ are not the same.

Comment: It relates to C++'s compatability with C, but it is not about the C language - thus the tag is inappropriate.

Comment: @Sammy : Are these errors coming from the declaration of the template, or from the usage?  If that latter, can you show the calls (and all associated declarations).  The Ubuntu error looks like you are making a call like `string_format( "Hello World" );`.  The Pi error looks like `std::string foo="foo"; string_format("Hello %s",foo);`

Comment: Thanks @MartinBonner. The call is as follows: std::string formatted_data = utils::Utils::string_format(str_format, args...); The method is defined as static  in a Utils library.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the calls.

Comment: The warning is a security warning as the function is abusable, e.g. `std::getline(std::cin, s); string_format(s, something);` might allow attacker to gain control of your process. You can disable it, as indicated in the error message, with `-Wno-format-security`

Comment: @MartinBonner: I have edited my post with complete code flow. I hope it is clearer now. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @Sammy -- `snprintf` is a C function, but you're passing something that is known only to C++.  That certainly isn't going to work reliably.  Also, if I read `18.10.3` of the C++ standard correctly, it is undefined behavior to pass anything that doesn't fit the parameter list.  In other words, you better be doing purely `C` or `C` compatible work if you're using `varargs` functions such as `snprintf`, `printf`, etc..

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to this ambiguity. Thanks @PaulMcKenzie for pointing out. Here was the solution I saw worked with any compiler flag such as "-Wno-format-security". No more error on Pi or Error on Ubuntu g++.

```
void main()
{   
    std::string linkName = getLinkName();

    // THIS IS THE CALL THAT LEADS TO THE ERROR AT COMPILE-TIME
    LOG_TRACE_FMT("\nLink-name: %s, Sent packet: SYS: %d, COMP: %d, LEN: %d, MSG ID: %d\n", linkName.c_str(), msg->sysid, msg->compid, msg->len, msg->msgid);
}
```

> The catch was doing linkName.c_str() (C-Style string) instead of passing the std::string as argument. This was tricky!

Comment: I'm surprised that the compiler emitted an error, and not just let you go shoot yourself in the foot at runtime when you passed a `std::string`.  The relevant section in the ANSI standard document (you can get a draft of it) that pertains to varargs functions is `18.10` in section 3:  *If the parameter parmN is declared with a function, array, or reference type, or with a type that is not compatible with the type that results when passing an argument for which there is no parameter, the behavior is undefined*

Comment: WARNING on g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609 but an ERROR on g++ (Raspbian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2. I agree the behavior can be undefined as above with passing the char array. I am glad that I found this at compile-time. The reason I often refrain from using Wno-format security format flag. It can be pretty dangerous at most unexpected times for critical applications. Thanks btw!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is causing your problems, but I don't see what benefit you gain from using a template function.  You can just use good-old-fashioned varargs for this.

I was going to say, that the golden rule for writing a varargs function is to write one which takes a `va_list`.  Your edit makes the reason for that very clear - you usually end up calling the varags function from another varargs function!

```
#include <stdarg.h>  // varargs support

static std::string string_vformat( const std::string& format, va_list args)
{
    va_list args_copy;
    va_copy(args,args_copy);  // Copy args before we use it.
                              // +1 is extra space for '\0'
    const size_t size = vsnprintf( nullptr, 0, format.c_str(), args_copy ) + 1; 
    va_end(args_copy);        // Release args_copy.
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf( new char[ size ] );
    vsnprintf( buf.get(), size, format.c_str(), args );
    // Caller must va_end(args);
           // We don't want the '\0' inside
    return std::string( buf.get(), buf.get() + size - 1 );
}

static std::string string_format( const std::string& format, ... )
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(format, args);
    const auto result = string_vformat(format, args);
    va_end(args);
    return result;
}

void user_log_fmt(LOG_LEVEL level,  std::string pretty_func, std::string func_name,
                                    std::string str_format, ... )
{
    if (m_LogLevel < level)
        return;

    va_list args;
    va_start(format, args);
    std::string formatted_data = utils::Utils::string_vformat(str_format, args);
    // Do something with the formatted string.. 
}
```

---

A couple of asides:

- I would allocate a writeable string with room for the `'\0'` and write into the buffer for that and then shrink the buffer afterwards to lose the terminator.  Strings are contiguous, so this is safe, and saving a dynamic allocation makes the cost of the extra byte in the final result very worthwhile.
- I would take all the arguments of `user_log_fmt` as const reference to `std::string` (but that's just because pass-by-value always makes me twitch).

---

Finally, as you appear to be using GCC, you can write:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
    #define PRINTFLIKE(n)  __attribute__(format,printf,(n),(n+1))
#else
    #define PRINTFLIKE(n)
#endif
```

and then you can declare:

```
 void user_log_fmt(LOG_LEVEL level, std::string pretty_func, std::string func_name,
                  std::string str_format, ... ) PRINTFLIKE(4)
```

and

```
 std::string string_format( const std::string& format, ... ) PRINTFLIKE(1)
```

Then GCC will issue you with a nice error if you do something like:

```
string_format( "Two things %d %d", only_one_thing );
```

(It will also complain if the format is the wrong type.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Bonner. I was trying understand what you suggested and compiling the same gives error.  

Are you sure you meant: 
va_start(format, args);

because the format must be void va_start(va_list ap, last_arg); I am using g++

Comment: Nope, I'm not sure in the least. This code has been nowhere near a compiler